# Will my dua be accepted after this?

Tags: dua, masturbation

Assalamualaikum,
I made a dua a week ago and I wanted it to complete. So for my dua to complete I did dua during prostration and rade Surah - Fath everyday and tried to lessen my sins. I used to do masturbation, so I decided to stop that. I was able to hold it for a week or so but then I did it. So will my dua be accepted after that.

Answer (score 0):

Repent from Allah and seek his forgiveness he is most merciful and just because we should not take risks make dua again but please brother leave this habit it gives a dark past May Allah have mercy and forgive us all Ameen ❤